# Получить результат асинхронной функции в синхронном модуле

Tags: python, python-3.5, асинхронность

Есть корутина

```
async def create_invite(session=session, answer_id="00000000"):
    guild = discord.utils.get(session.guilds, id=721664870235242537)
    guild_info = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name='info')
    return await guild_info.create_invite(max_age=86400, max_uses=1, reason="[" + str(answer_id) + "]")
```

И есть не асинхронная функция, в которой нужно получить результат этой корутины:

```
def questions(request):
    ds_link = create_invite(answer_id="hello, world!") # нужно получить результат create_invite
    return render(request, 'weekly/discord.html', {'discord_link':ds_link})
```

Функция `questions` нельзя сделать асинхронной. Есть ли способы достать результат из корутины в данной ситуации?

---

Контекст задачи:

> Работаю над интеграцией `discord.py` в свой django-проект. Стоит задача в Django-представлении сгенерировать ссылку-приглашение на дискорд и отправить её в рендер шаблона. Версия Django - 2.2.5, Python - 3.5.7

Comment: `asgiref.sync.async_to_sync` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/async/#async-adapter-functions

Comment: @andreymal обновил метки и контекст. Есть ли решения для Django2 ?

Comment: Модуль asgiref можно установить хоть для Django1, так что решение то же самое

Comment: Хотя вот с Python 3.5 это вы очень зря конечно